# Matrice 210 RTK Hardwars Sync

Tags: dji-sdk

We are trying to follow the guide for hardware sync support to sync the clock of our remote sensors to the hardware sync clock described in the link below. We are using the matrice 210 and do not have the options to configure the pin outs for hardware sync in dji assistant. I can programmatically set the frequency through the onboard SDK as described in the link

https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-hardware-sync.html

vehicle->hardSync->setSyncFreq(200,999);

, but we cannot figure out how to configure which pin the time sync will go out on.

The tools option in DJI assistant does NOT exist as shown in the link for configuring this(see screen shot). I have tried both the DJI assistant2 as well as the Assistant 2 for Matrice and both don’t have the window.[DJI Assistant 2 Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9cwi.jpg)

I saw in the manual for the matrice 210 that it call out the expansion ports can be configured in the DJI Pilot app. I do see the configuration to configure these, but it has no options to define the port as a hardware_sync pin. Is there any way to programmatically assign the pin out for the hardware sync in the OSDK? If not how do I assign one of the multi function IO ports as the hardware synch port?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue right now. If you look [here](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/appendix/releaseNotes.html) in section OSDK 3.4 highlights it says "OSDK features are now supported for M210. Currently, hardware synchronization and Multi-function IO are not supported."

And it's not mentioned later if it's already implemented or not. So I think it could be still in development.

It would be nice if developers could comment on questions here related to `dji_sdk` from time to time...

(Btw this is not an answer, but I'm posting it as one because stackoverflow won't let you comment with reputation less than 50 for some reason...)